# FlexCan FIFO Overrun

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, drivers, arm

I'm working on a custom board equipped with an ARM CPU Module. 
Operating system is Linux (kernel v3.16.x).

I applied Patch 8234.
http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.can/8234

Receiving and sending standard messages is fine. But using extended format does not work.

Can someone give me some guidance on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved in kernel 4.11.x